# Mule - Dynamic file inbound endpoint error

Tags: file, dynamic, mule, endpoint, inbound

My ESB flow needs to get files from a dynamic folder. This folder name changes based on month and year. Hence, I configured my inbound-endpoint as shown below but I am getting below error. I really appreciate any help on this.

*Flow:*

```xml
<flow name="DataMapperTestFlow" doc:name="DataMapperTestFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\#[new Date().format('yyyy\\MMMM')]" moveToDirectory="C:\#[new Date().format('yyyy\\MMMM')]\backup" pollingFrequency="10000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern=".*.xls" caseSensitive="true"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <custom-transformer class="ExcelToJava" doc:name="Java"/>
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="insertTestHeaders" connector-ref="NewDatabase" doc:name="InsertHeaders"/>
    <set-payload value="#[payload.excelData.excelRows]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="insertTestRows" connector-ref="NewDatabase" doc:name="InsertRows"/>
</flow>
```

*Error:*

> org.mule.api.endpoint.MalformedEndpointException: The endpoint
>   "file:///C:/#[new Date().format('yyyy/MMMM')]" is malformed and cannot
>   be parsed.   If this is the name of a global endpoint, check the name
>   is correct, that the endpoint exists, and that you are using the
>   correct configuration (eg the "ref" attribute).   Note that names on
>   inbound and outbound endpoints cannot be used to send or receive
>   messages; use a named global endpoint instead.. Only Outbound
>   endpoints can be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

"Only Outbound endpoints can be dynamic" quite says it all. You can have a look at the [Mule Requester Module](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introducing-mule-requester) if it suits your needs, or try creating endpoints/flows programmatically with a scheduler and Java/Groovy/etc code.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I tried this groovy expression as well (path="C:\#[groovy:new Date().format('yyyy\\MMMM')]") but it didn't work.  I believe if we use "Mule Requester Module" we need to explicitly trigger the flow but here the polling needs to be automatic.